# How to fix CO2 regulator that leaks out of the adjustment screw hole?

Tags: co2

I've recently discovered that my CO2 regulator is leaking out of the adjustment screw hole. I took out the 4 screws, removed the bonnet ([as suggested here](http://www.weekendbrewer.com/Checking_for_Co2_Leaks.htm)), and replaced it. The leak now seems to be less severe than it was, but it is still present.

What can I do to fix this leak?

Answer (score 2):

maybe try wrapping some teflon tape on the threads like you do with a natural gas line?

Answer (score 1):

Take the regulator and a 12-pack of beer to a gas supply shop and see if someone there will look it over for you and fix it for beer.

Comment: aka "stick to what you're good at". I love it.